# What's the best way to center using CSS?

Tags: html, css

What's the best way to center using CSS?

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 50%;">
    <div style="position: relative; left: -50%">
        Centered content
    </div>
</div>
```

or just

```
    <div style="text-align:center">
        Centered content
    </div>
```

?

Edit: ok, so I should use "text-align:center" for inline elements and "margin: 0 auto" for block elemtns
Thank you.

Comment: body { margin: 0 auto; }

Comment: Center text?  Or center block elements?

Comment: @bksi: I prefer printing out the content, putting onto a wooden table, using a ruler to center it, taking a photo, printing the photo, then scanning it back in.

Comment: Truly depends on what you are centering, and whether its horizontally or vertically centered or both...  This is too open-ended.

Comment: @Brad: Umm....anything, I guess.

Comment: @user2994067 There isn't a "one-size-fits-all." It depends on what element/content you want to center and on which axis.

Comment: I'm thinking vertically it's with the "position" things. But just horizontally, it's the "text-align"... is it?

Comment: There are many, many ways to center with CSS and determining which to use is based on the situation. Google it. There are tons of specific posts on SO already.

Answer (score 4):

First one is gnarly, don't see something like that much, text-align:center is quite reliable for inline elements but when an element won't center margin: 0 auto; my is my old standby.

```
<div style="text-align:center">
        Centered content
</div>
```

or

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto;">
        Centered content
</div>
```

And like BenM said, margin: 0 auto; centers display:block elements that have a defined width.

So what is margin: 0 auto; doing? Well 0 sets the top and bottom margin to be 0 and auto tells the browser to calculate the the left and right margin and the browser will do so by assigning equal values to the left and right margin of any element with the margin: 0 auto; style.

Comment: You should explain the differences between centering text and centering block elements so it is clear when to use each example you have provided.

Comment: The second example (i.e. `margin: 0 auto`) only works if `<div>` has a specific width.

Comment: And then you also probably need to use display:block; when using margin auto.

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way is to give the element a width and then specify `margin: 0 auto`.

For example:

```
div {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are centering `inline` element you should use `text-align:center` on the parent

If it is `block` element - use `margin: 0 auto;`

```
 p {
      text-align:center;
 }


 div { 
     width: 100px;
     margin:0 auto;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Text-align: center; will only center the text inside the div element. To center the whole block element you will need to add margin: 0 auto; or position it with position: absolute/relative depending on how you like to center it (parent element/ body etc.)